# access sub runs once then Error '91': object variable not set

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, runtime-error

Thank you for any help in advance,

I have an Access database which contains the following code. It is setup to open an defined excel file, locate the last row and add 1 to the value of that row in the next row below, save etc... It does this the first time, if you run it again I get "Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set". however, if I hit the stop button (reset) in the VBA window or the End button on the error message, then run it again it works. I've tried many things and I'm at a loss.

Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub quoteNew1_Click()

    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    app.Visible = True

    Dim book As Excel.Workbook
    Set book = app.Workbooks.Add("C:\Desktop\Test_Quotes.xlsx") 

    nextEmptyRow  'find last row and add new value to next row colum a

    book.Close savechanges:=True

    app.Quit
    Set app = Nothing

End Sub


Sub nextEmptyRow()
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    emptyRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    MsgBox emptyRow

    Cells(emptyRow + 1, 1).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value + 1

End Sub
```

Kind regards,

Comment: You get the Error 91 _where_?

Comment: if i was to guess, I would remove or alter the set app = Nothing, if it works first time I get the impression this statement has worked and is blocking the next attempt. error 91 can be caused by"attempted to use an object variable that has been set to Nothing. "

Comment: It could be that you're not entirely cleaning up after yourself: you set `app` to Nothing, but not `book`. Do this after the `.Close` and before `Set app = Nothing`.

Comment: Matteo, the Error 91 highlights the `emptyRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: n34, I removed the `app = Nothing` and still received the error.

Comment: Mark, I added `book = Nothing` to help clean up after myself. Thank you for the advice, I agree I am not the best at cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workbooks.Add wants a template as an argument.  You will want to use the format below for adding a new workbook the first time.  After that, you will want to open the existing workbook.  The following code works for me and appears to meet your requirement of adding a new row each time with an incremented value.

```
Private Sub quoteNew1_Click()

Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Visible = True

Dim book As Excel.Workbook

'If workbook exists open it, otherwise create it
If Len(Dir("C:\temparea\Test_Quotes.xlsx")) = 0 Then
    'File doesn't exist, create it
    Set book = Workbooks.Add
    app.DisplayAlerts = False
    book.SaveAs FileName:="C:\temparea\Test_Quotes.xlsx"
    app.DisplayAlerts = False
Else
    'Open existing file
    Set book = Workbooks.Open("C:\temparea\Test_Quotes.xlsx")
End If

nextEmptyRow  'find last row and add new value to next row colum a

book.Close savechanges:=True

app.Quit
Set app = Nothing
End Sub

Sub nextEmptyRow()
Dim emptyRow As Long

emptyRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

If Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value + 1
Else
    Cells(emptyRow + 1, 1).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value + 1
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: pghcpa, this did fix my issue, I still used my original code but yours helped me identify what was wrong with mine by comparing the two, I was using `Set book = app.workbooks.add` , which you pointed out needed an additional argument, when I only needed to use `workbooks.open` this did eliminate my error. I greatly appreciate all the input from everyone!